# Как правильно составить триггер в MySQL на подсчет данных и обновление записи в другой таблице

Tags: mysql, update, insert, триггеры-sql

Есть таблица prosedures после добавления в нее новой записи надо надо найти в ней значение casenum - идентификатор документа.
Затем сравнить если в таблице applycant запись с таким же номером, там тоже есть колонка casenum. Если номера совпадают то в колонку stageount таблицы applycant количество записей с совпадающим номером.
Подскажите как это реализовать?
С триггерами не очень знаком.

Comment: Выполните действия, описанные в [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: дело и не в триггерах. Вы для сначала обозначьте свое искомое значение как `x` и напишите запрос, которые ищет и обновляет то что надо.  Потом возьмите создайте триггер, и вместо `x` подставьте `new.casenum`